# Excel - Advanced Filter: Filter values greater than today

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm trying to make use of Advanced Filter instead of AutoFilter as I'm told it performs much better in VBA. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to filter data to **only show dates greater than today** since that is dynamic and relies on a formula.

I've tried making my criteria range `>today()` and `">"&B2` where `B2` is `today()`

Any idea what I'm missing?

Advanced Filter:

[image]

Data before:

[image: before]

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: try using `> Now`

Comment: Same issue as `>today()`

Comment: Can you show more of your code so the issue can be easily reproduced?

Comment: your formula must us the first cell in the data column as reference.  So say the date column in the data is in Column C and the first cell of data is C2 the formula in the criteria would be `=C2>TODAY()`  it may show TRUE or FALSE but the filter will filter correctly. See https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/09/14/use-advanced-filter-excel-criteria-range-examples/

Comment: With your data use `=A2>TODAY()`

Comment: And the criteria range is `E1:E2`

Comment: Thanks, @ScottCraner. I tried that, but now it's filtering out everything. Is there something different about datetime data?

Comment: remove the `Date` from E1  leave it blank but still keep the criteria range as E1:E2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a formula in Advanced filter the formula itself is the filter.  Remove the title from the criteria and point the formula at the first cell in the column data to be filtered.  In this case:

```
=A2>TODAY()
```

So:

[image]

The Criteria must include the blank cell above:

[image]

And we get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Criteria value should be:

```
Set Today as Date
...
Today = Date
```

if you are referring to today's date. Today is an Excel Function, not vba function.

Sorry, but I can not make comments still. Hope it helps.